# onActivityResult not being called in calling activity

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have a FragmentActivity that is starting another activity for result.  When the called activity finishes, onActivityResult is not called.  Does it make a difference that I am using a AppCompatActivity activity (which extends from FragmentActivity)?  The documentation says that results will be returned to the calling fragment, and in this case it's not a fragment, it's an activity.   Here is the code, very simple:

MainActivity:

```
public class SMSEmailActivityNew extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      //setup activity....
      Intent i = new Intent(this, EulaActivity.class);
      i.putExtra(Globals.keyFileName,Globals.FILE_EULA );
      startActivityForResult(i,RESULT_OK);
   }

   //this method is never called
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
      //dowork .....
   }

}
```

Called activity:

```
EulaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //set up activity ....
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent result = new Intent();
       if (bPermissionGranted) {
           setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
           // Determine if EULA was accepted this time

         getSharedPreferences().edit().putBoolean(Globals.KEY_EULA_ACCEPTED, true).apply();

        } else {
           setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, result);
        }
        finish();

  }


}
```

Comment: Try with extending DisplayTextActivity from  AppCompatActivity.

Comment: @FerdousAhamed that did not work.

Comment: Your called activity is EulaActivity not DisplayTextActivity

Comment: Use your own request code like `123`, idk.

Comment: The result is set if permission is granted.  I don't see that in the code.

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin even if I didn't use my own request code, onActivityResult should still be called.

Comment: make sure your onClick method is called and try using setResult(RESULT_OK, result);

Comment: It has, because it need to be bigger than 0. and `RESULT_OK` is -1. You need to call `startActivityForResult` with your own id bigger than 0.

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin that was indeed it.  Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) you need to pass `requestId` bigger or equal thant 0. In your case `RESULT_OK` is `-1`. Also `RESULT_OK` acts like result code, not like request code and `startActivityForResult` needs a request code.

Something like this `startActivityForResult(intent, 0);`

Also finish `EulaActivity` using `finishActivity(yourPreviousRequestCode);`, in this case `0`.

Comment: I have been searching for this all over. Thanks for the answer. This helped me a lot

Comment: Searched almost across the internet. Finally this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:-

MainActivity.java

```
//Define variable
public static int REQUEST_CODE = 233;

public class SMSEmailActivityNew extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      //setup activity....
      Intent i = new Intent(this, EulaActivity.class);
      i.putExtra(Globals.keyFileName,Globals.FILE_EULA );
      startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);   //Change here
   }

   //this method is never called
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
      if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if(data != null && data.hasExtra("MESSAGE")) {
                    String resStr = data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, resStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
   }

}
```

EulaActivity.java

```
EulaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //set up activity ....
}

public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent result = new Intent();
   result.putExtra("MESSAGE","Eula Accepted Set");
   if (bPermissionGranted) {
       setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
       // Determine if EULA was accepted this time

     getSharedPreferences().edit().putBoolean(Globals.KEY_EULA_ACCEPTED, true).apply();

    } else {
       setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, result);
    }
    finish();

  }


}
```